# Interact with Metro application from Win32

Tags: windows-8, wmi, microsoft-metro

I have a traditional Win32 program which gets some data using WMI (and it cannot be fetched using API available to Metro apps). Now I want to make a tile with part of this information. As I've understood, it's impossible to simply send this data from Win32 program to the Metro application. What's the preferred way to do such thing?

Comment: If it's impossible, doesn't that imply that there's no way of doing it? And further, doesn't it also imply that there would be no preferred way of doing it?

Comment: @LarryOsterman, however, there are ways to send data (look at the answers). They are indirect, but they should work.

Comment: @HCL: You can't access localhost from a store app. And don't forget that the app certification requirements require that an app be fully functional and useful on its own - it can't require the Win32 app to function properly.

Comment: @LarryOsterman: Now I'm programming just for fun, with no commercial expectations and not going to publish it to the market, so I can ignore app certification requirements. However, it seems rather unfriendly from Microsoft to apply such API restrictions to Metro applications.

Comment: @LarryOsterman: and as for accessing localhost - Metro apps can access some folders on the machine, such as documents or app local folder.

Comment: That's local filesystem access, not network access. localhost is used for network access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct app to app communication method.  What you want to do can be accomplished in several ways, however.  Your Win32 app could write data to a location on the file system that a Metro style has access to.  Also, you could synchronize your Win32 app with your Metro style app using the cloud.  You need to be careful, however, as this might violate some of the [app certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh694083).

Comment: I don't want to require Internet connection, so creating file in a directory like app local directory seem to be the solution. And what's the reliable way to determine the location of this directory (`ms-appdata:///local/` in Metro app)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply writing something for yourself (not concerned with publish your app), you might consider taking the functionality that currently have within your desktop app and encapsulating it within a wcf service running on localhost. Metro apps can call wcf services.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have your Win32 program create the tile XML and deposit in Windows Azure storage (or really anything accessible via a URI) and then your Windows 8 Store application could subscribe to that tile via a [Periodic Notification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/30/windows-8-notifications-using-azure-for-periodic-notifications.aspx).

There are some constraints here which may or may not be relevant to your application - like the refresh rate of the tile (discrete periods from 30 minutes to 1 day) and the machine must be connected to the network when the poll from the URL is made.

You might be able to incorporate a [background task](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27411) to do something similar.